# Do the bullets fired at the final enemy in an area subtract from your total ammunition?

Tags: max-payne-3

In Max Payne 3, when you start shooting the final enemy in an area, the game goes into a slow motion "overkill mode" (not sure if there's a proper term for it) allowing you to fire many rounds at the unfortunate straggler.

Is the ammunition used in these "overkill" sequences subtracted from your total ammunition?

Comment: Is it called "last man standing"? Or does that only apply when you are almost dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your ammunition is used up in those sequences. You can just go with the one bullet for the kill, or empty the clip, but it will use the ammunition up.

Sometimes it can be hard to keep track of bullets used as some of the cinematics will force the weapon to be switched, and I found sometimes if you emptied a clip it would reload for you.